# how to fix fluentd(td-agent) buffer problem?

Tags: fluentd

I have an fluentd, elasticsearch, graylog setup and I'm getting below error intermittently in td-agent log

> [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2019-01-27
>   19:00:14 -0500 error_class="ArgumentError" error="Data too big (189382
>   bytes), would create more than 128 chunks!"
>   plugin_id="object:3fee25617fbc"

Because of this cache memory increases and td-agent fails to send messages to graylog

I have tried setting the buffer_chunk_limit to 8m and flush_interval time to 5sec

Comment: What have you already tried to fix this?

Comment: I have tried setting the buffer_chunk_limit to 8m and flush_interval time to 5sec

Comment: Can you please provide your fluentd configuration?.